# Postgresql logical replication suddenly stop (wal status is extended, An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

Tags: postgresql, replication, backup, windows-server, postgresql-14

I checked the replication status of our production server when i noticed that one of the replicated DB is missing (using pg_stat_replication command).
I also check the replication slots and found out that the assigned slot for the replicated db has a  wal status equal to extended.

What should i do to fix and continue the logical replication process?
I'm using Postgresql 14 for windows.

Comment: You should start the standby and look at its log to figure out if it is happy, and if not, why.

Comment: My apology but my experience for this replication is not much. I don't know how to re-execute it. For the meantime what i did was to disable the subscription.

Comment: this is what i found in the logs : CONTEXT:  slot "truckerapp14_subscribe", output plugin "pgoutput", in the change callback, associated LSN 2/18A973B8
2023-05-11 00:00:04.350 UTC [6076] STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "truckerapp14_subscribe" LOGICAL 2/18A4AFB8 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_truckerapp14"')
2023-05-11 00:00:09.705 UTC [7244] LOG:  starting logical decoding for slot "truckerapp14_subscribe"
2023-05-11 00:00:09.705 UTC [7244] DETAIL:  Streaming transactions committing after 2/18A73A50, reading WAL from 2/18A4AFF8.

Comment: If you disabled the subscription, it is to be expected that it does not replicate and therefore is missing from `pg_stat_replication`. Enable the subscription and check the log again.

Comment: logical replication is currently enabled but still missing in the pg_stat_replication. under replication slots, wal status is still extended.

Comment: Great. Then return to my original advice, look at the log of the standby and see why it is unhappy.

Comment: 2023-05-15 07:48:50.411 UTC [11212] LOG:  starting logical decoding for slot "truckerapp14_subscribe"
2023-05-15 07:48:50.411 UTC [11212] DETAIL:  Streaming transactions committing after 2/18A73A50, reading WAL from 2/18A4AFF8.
2023-05-15 07:48:50.411 UTC [11212] STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "truckerapp14_subscribe" LOGICAL 2/18A4AFB8 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_truckerapp14"')
2023-05-15 07:48:50.411 UTC [11212] LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 2/18A4AFF8
2023-05-15 07:48:50.411 UTC [11212] DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.

Comment: Does this mean that the wal cannot be read?

Comment: That looks like everything is fine. Perform a change, and see if it is replicated. If not, look at the log again.

Comment: i found this one 
2023-05-15 08:08:50.393 UTC [3624] STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "truckerapp14_subscribe" LOGICAL 2/18A4AFB8 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_truckerapp14"')
2023-05-15 08:08:50.431 UTC [3624] LOG:  could not send data to client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: Just look at the relevant portions of the log files on both servers, [edit] the question and add them there.

Comment: I can't resolve the issue. The replication doesn't start. I think the best way was to recreate again the logical replication. Thanks for the advice.